# Here Maps Marker plot with address

Tags: here-api, heremaps

I have full address (Ex: 31, High Street, New York - 10001, United States of America), I need to plot this address as a marked on Here Maps. Can address be used to plot marker?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the below steps to add a marker on your given address at here maps:

**Step 1.** Please refer to the below example makes a geocoding request and retrieve the latitude, longitude, and complete address details of 31, High Street, New York - 10001, United States of America based on free-form text input. A clickable marker is placed on the location found.

### HTML Snippet:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Search for a Location based on an Address</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="demo.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../template.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src='../test-credentials.js'></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-service.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-mapevents.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body id="geocode">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Search for a Location based on an Address</h1>
        <p>Request a location using a free-form text input and display it on the map.</p>
    </div>
    <p>This example makes a geocoding request and retrieves the latitude, longitude and 
      complete address details of <b>31, High Street, New York - 10001, United States of America</b> based on a free-form 
      text input. A clickable marker is placed on the location found.</p>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="panel"></div>
    <h3>Code</h3>
    <p>Access to the geocoding service is obtained from the <code>H.service.Platform</code>
       by calling <code>getSearchService()</code>. The <code>geocode()</code> method is used 
       to find a location by passing in the relevant <code>q</code> parameter as defined in 
       <a href="https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/dev_guide/topics/endpoint-geocode-brief.html" target="_blank">Geocoding and Search API v7</a>. 
       The styling and display of the response are under the developer's control.</p>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='demo.js'></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

**Javascript Snippet:**

```
/**
 * Calculates and displays the address details of 31, High Street, New York - 10001, United States of America
 * based on a free-form text
 * A full list of available request parameters can be found in the Geocoder API documentation.
 * see: http://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/geocoder/topics/resource-geocode.html
 * @param   {H.service.Platform} platform    A stub class to access HERE services
 */
function geocode(platform) {
  var geocoder = platform.getSearchService(),
      geocodingParameters = {
        q: '31, High Street, New York - 10001, United States of America'
      };

  geocoder.geocode(
    geocodingParameters,
    onSuccess,
    onError
  );
}
/**
 * This function will be called once the Geocoder REST API provides a response
 * @param  {Object} result          A JSONP object representing the  location(s) found.
 *
 * see: http://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/geocoder/topics/resource-type-response-geocode.html
 */
function onSuccess(result) {
  var locations = result.items;
 /*
  * The styling of the geocoding response on the map is entirely under the developer's control.
  * A representative styling can be found in the full JS + HTML code of this example
  * in the functions below:
  */
  addLocationsToMap(locations);
  addLocationsToPanel(locations);
  // ... etc.
}

/**
 * This function will be called if a communication error occurs during the JSON-P request
 * @param  {Object} error  The error message received.
 */
function onError(error) {
  alert('Can\'t reach the remote server');
}

/**
 * Boilerplate map initialization code starts below:
 */

//Step 1: initialize communication with the platform
// In your own code, replace variable window.apikey with your own apikey
var platform = new H.service.Platform({
  apikey: window.apikey
});
var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();

//Step 2: initialize a map - this map is centered over New York
var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
  defaultLayers.vector.normal.map,{
  center: {lat:41.033, lng:-73.7471},
  zoom: 15,
  pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio || 1
});
// add a resize listener to make sure that the map occupies the whole container
window.addEventListener('resize', () => map.getViewPort().resize());

var locationsContainer = document.getElementById('panel');

//Step 3: make the map interactive
// MapEvents enables the event system
// Behavior implements default interactions for pan/zoom (also on mobile touch environments)
var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));

// Create the default UI components
var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers);

// Hold a reference to any infobubble opened
var bubble;

/**
 * Opens/Closes a infobubble
 * @param  {H.geo.Point} position     The location on the map.
 * @param  {String} text              The contents of the infobubble.
 */
function openBubble(position, text){
 if(!bubble){
    bubble =  new H.ui.InfoBubble(
      position,
      {content: text});
    ui.addBubble(bubble);
  } else {
    bubble.setPosition(position);
    bubble.setContent(text);
    bubble.open();
  }
}

/**
 * Creates a series of list items for each location found, and adds it to the panel.
 * @param {Object[]} locations An array of locations as received from the
 *                             H.service.GeocodingService
 */
function addLocationsToPanel(locations){

  var nodeOL = document.createElement('ul'),
      i;

  nodeOL.style.fontSize = 'small';
  nodeOL.style.marginLeft ='5%';
  nodeOL.style.marginRight ='5%';


   for (i = 0;  i < locations.length; i += 1) {
     let location = locations[i];
     var li = document.createElement('li'),
          divLabel = document.createElement('div'),
          address = location.address,
          content =  '<strong style="font-size: large;">' + address.label  + '</strong></br>';
          position = location.position;

      content += '<strong>houseNumber:</strong> ' + address.houseNumber + '<br/>';
      content += '<strong>street:</strong> '  + address.street + '<br/>';
      content += '<strong>district:</strong> '  + address.district + '<br/>';
      content += '<strong>city:</strong> ' + address.city + '<br/>';
      content += '<strong>postalCode:</strong> ' + address.postalCode + '<br/>';
      content += '<strong>county:</strong> ' + address.county + '<br/>';
      content += '<strong>country:</strong> ' + address.countryName + '<br/>';
      content += '<strong>position:</strong> ' +
        Math.abs(position.lat.toFixed(4)) + ((position.lat > 0) ? 'N' : 'S') +
        ' ' + Math.abs(position.lng.toFixed(4)) + ((position.lng > 0) ? 'E' : 'W') + '<br/>';

      divLabel.innerHTML = content;
      li.appendChild(divLabel);

      nodeOL.appendChild(li);
  }

  locationsContainer.appendChild(nodeOL);
}


/**
 * Creates a series of H.map.Markers for each location found, and adds it to the map.
 * @param {Object[]} locations An array of locations as received from the
 *                             H.service.GeocodingService
 */
function addLocationsToMap(locations){
  var group = new  H.map.Group(),
      position,
      i;

  // Add a marker for each location found
  for (i = 0;  i < locations.length; i += 1) {
    let location = locations[i];
    marker = new H.map.Marker(location.position);
    marker.label = location.address.label;
    group.addObject(marker);
  }

  group.addEventListener('tap', function (evt) {
    map.setCenter(evt.target.getGeometry());
    openBubble(
       evt.target.getGeometry(), evt.target.label);
  }, false);

  // Add the locations group to the map
  map.addObject(group);
  map.setCenter(group.getBoundingBox().getCenter());
}

// Now use the map as required...
geocode(platform);
```

---

### CSS Snippet:

```
#geocode #map {
    display: block;
    width: 95%;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    height: 450px;
    background: grey;
}

#geocode #panel {
    display: block;
    width: 95%;
    min-height: 450px;
    max-height: 450px;
    border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
}
```

**Refer to the documentation for more details: https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/maps-js/services/geocode-a-location-from-address

Code: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/2.1.0/heremaps/maps-api-for-javascript-examples/tree/master/map-with-dom-marker**

---

**Step 2:** This example displays a movable map of New York with a single marker highlighting the location of High Street (41.8625°N, 87.6166°W), your home. Marker displays the letter C in the correct club colors. The marker is capable of receiving DOM (Document Object Model) events such as mouseenter, mouseleave etc. The marker will fade if the mouse pointer is placed over it.

**HTML Snippet:**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    
    <title>DOM Marker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="demo.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../template.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src='../test-credentials.js'></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-service.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-mapevents.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body id="markers-on-the-map">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>DOM Marker</h1>
        <p>Display a marker that is capable of receiving DOM events</p>
    </div>
    <p>This example displays a movable map of <b>New York</b> with a single marker 
      highlighting the location of High Street <i>(41.033°N, 73.7471°W)</i>, 
      your home. Marker displays the letter C in the correct club colors.</p>
    <p>The marker is capable of receiving DOM (Document Object Model) events such as <code>mouseenter</code>, 
      <code>mouseleave</code> etc. The marker will fade if the mouse pointer is placed over it.</p>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <h3>Code</h3>
    <p>DOM markers are created by using the <code>H.map.DomMarker</code> class by providing a <code>H.map.DomIcon</code>.</p>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='demo.js'></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

### **Java Script Snippet:**

```
/**
 * Create a marker that is capable of receiving DOM events and add it
 * to the map.
 * @param  {H.Map} map      A HERE Map instance within the application
 */
function addDomMarker(map) {
  var outerElement = document.createElement('div'),
      innerElement = document.createElement('div');

  outerElement.style.userSelect = 'none';
  outerElement.style.webkitUserSelect = 'none';
  outerElement.style.msUserSelect = 'none';
  outerElement.style.mozUserSelect = 'none';
  outerElement.style.cursor = 'default';

  innerElement.style.color = 'red';
  innerElement.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
  innerElement.style.border = '2px solid black';
  innerElement.style.font = 'normal 12px arial';
  innerElement.style.lineHeight = '12px'

  innerElement.style.paddingTop = '2px';
  innerElement.style.paddingLeft = '4px';
  innerElement.style.width = '20px';
  innerElement.style.height = '20px';

  // add negative margin to inner element
  // to move the anchor to center of the div
  innerElement.style.marginTop = '-10px';
  innerElement.style.marginLeft = '-10px';

  outerElement.appendChild(innerElement);

  // Add text to the DOM element
  innerElement.innerHTML = 'C';

  function changeOpacity(evt) {
    evt.target.style.opacity = 0.6;
  };

  function changeOpacityToOne(evt) {
    evt.target.style.opacity = 1;
  };

  //create dom icon and add/remove opacity listeners
  var domIcon = new H.map.DomIcon(outerElement, {
    // the function is called every time marker enters the viewport
    onAttach: function(clonedElement, domIcon, domMarker) {
      clonedElement.addEventListener('mouseover', changeOpacity);
      clonedElement.addEventListener('mouseout', changeOpacityToOne);
    },
    // the function is called every time marker leaves the viewport
    onDetach: function(clonedElement, domIcon, domMarker) {
      clonedElement.removeEventListener('mouseover', changeOpacity);
      clonedElement.removeEventListener('mouseout', changeOpacityToOne);
    }
  });

  // Marker for Chicago Bears home
  var bearsMarker = new H.map.DomMarker({lat: 41.033, lng: -73.7471}, {
    icon: domIcon
  });
  map.addObject(bearsMarker);
}

/**
 * Boilerplate map initialization code starts below:
 */

//Step 1: initialize communication with the platform
// In your own code, replace variable window.apikey with your own apikey
var platform = new H.service.Platform({
  apikey: window.apikey
});
var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();

//Step 2: initialize a map - this map is centered over Chicago.
var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
  defaultLayers.vector.normal.map,{
  center: {lat:41.881944, lng:-87.627778},
  zoom: 11,
  pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio || 1
});
// add a resize listener to make sure that the map occupies the whole container
window.addEventListener('resize', () => map.getViewPort().resize());

//Step 3: make the map interactive
// MapEvents enables the event system
// Behavior implements default interactions for pan/zoom (also on mobile touch environments)
var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));


// Now use the map as required...
addDomMarker(map);
```

---

**CSS Snippet:**

```
#map {
    width: 95%;
    height: 450px;
    background: grey;
}

#panel {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
}
```

**Refer DOM Marker document for more details: https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/maps-js/markers/map-with-dom-marker

Code: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/2.1.0/heremaps/maps-api-for-javascript-examples/tree/master/map-with-dom-marker**

TC